# Can Lazybones be configured to ignore certain variables?

Tags: groovy, lazybones

[Lazybones](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones) here. Any recommendations/hacks/workaround for when the post-templated file needs to have `${...}`-style tokens in it that should be *ignored* by lazybones?

For example, a sample `application.yml` file for a Spring Boot app:

```
logging:
  config: 'logback.groovy'
${appname}:
  configWaitForAnswerMillis: ${configTime}
```

Say I want lazybones to replace `${appname}` with the name of the app I'm generating, but I want lazybones to ignore `${configTime}` so that the resultant YAML file might look like:

```
logging:
  config: 'logback.groovy'
myapp:
  configWaitForAnswerMillis: ${configTime}
```

Any suggestions here? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you just need to escape `$` like `\${configTime}`

Comment: Thanks (+1) -- it appears lazybones' default template engine is [`SimpleTemplateEngine`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html). Does your proposed solution work with that engine?